# Dynamically initializing object properties with Automapper?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, automapper

I am looking to initialize a set of view model objects that look a little bit like this:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public GraphModel SomeGraph { get; set; }
    public GraphModel SomeGraph2 { get; set; }
    public TableModel SomeTable { get; set; }
    public GraphModel SomeGraph3 { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    public GraphModel SomeGraph { get; set; }
    public TableModel SomeGraph2 { get; set; }
    public TableModel SomeTable { get; set; }
    public FieldModel SomeField { get; set; }
}
```

now I could just explicitly initialize them with `new TableModel()` and `new GraphModel()` but I really rather have this be done dynamically, so I built a procedure that iterates all the properties and fills them with a set of predefined initializers for each type:

```
new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>
    {
        {typeof (...), () => new ...{x = y}},
        {typeof (...), () => new ...{z = y, c = g}},
        {typeof (...), () => new ...{z = q}},
        {typeof (...), () => new ...{x = y}},
    };
```

Since I have many of those and reflection cost is high I was wondering **if the same could be achieved with some kind of default type-based mapping in AutoMapper** since I guess it eventually uses cached precompiled expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) to generate some Factory or just BeforeMap method for AutoMapper configuration?
Let's say you have the following class which holds all initializers.

```
namespace App
{
    public class Defaults
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _initializer = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>
        {
            {typeof (FieldModel), () => new FieldModel {X = "X"}},
            {typeof (TableModel), () => new TableModel {Y = "Y", Z = "Z"}}
        };

        public static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> Initializer
        {
            get { return _initializer; }
            set { _initializer = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Then add Text Template like below:

[image]

And as a result of the transformation we get a file with the following content:

```
public class Factory
{
    public App.ModelA Initizlize(App.ModelA source)
    {
         source.SomeTable = (App.TableModel)App.Defaults.Initializer[typeof(App.TableModel)].Invoke();
         return source;
    }
    public App.ModelB Initizlize(App.ModelB source)
    {
         source.SomeGraph2 = (App.TableModel)App.Defaults.Initializer[typeof(App.TableModel)].Invoke();
         return source;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.olegsych.com/) is really good resource about T4.